# jQuery mobile + phonegap select element displays options very slow

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a jQuery mobile + phonegap mobile app for Android/iOS.  However I am having a problem with a select element on Android.  When it is clicked, it takes almost 5 seconds to then display the options.  I have noticed it doesn't take this long on other pages that have fewer HTML elements or iOS.

Is there a way I can speed this process up?

Comment: about how many elements do we talk?

Comment: It is dependent on what gets returned from the server.  This is being used on a search via the app, the number of items could be anywhere from 0-hundreds of objects, which is then parsed for information and inserted into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this issue:

> **$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay**
>
> If you find that the button
>   down/hover state (lists, buttons, links etc) feels sluggish the
>   $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay setting might be of use. It will
>   decrease the time between the touch event and the application of the
>   relevant class but will also result in a higher chance that the same
>   class will be applied even when the user is scrolling (eg, over a long
>   list of links).
>
> http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/phonegap.html